# Symfony2 - unable to autoload JMS serializer annotations

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, jms-serializer

We are having issues autoloading JMSSerializer annotations in a symfony app. We are getting: 

`[Semantical Error] The annotation "@JMS\Serializer\Annotation\XMLRoot" in class Class\Namespace\ClassName does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.`

We are using the standard symfony/composer autoloader, have `"jms/serializer-bundle": "~1.0"` required in composer.json, and include the bundle in the AppKernel. Other annotations (e.g symfony route annotations) work correctly.

We tried forcing to load the jms serializer annotations by modifying app_dev.php to:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("/srv/httpd/project/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/XmlRoot.php");
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('JMS\Serializer', "/srv/httpd/project/vendor/jms/serializer/src/");

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

We tried several variations of the `AnnotationRegistery::...` calls. `AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("/srv/httpd/project/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/Annotation/XmlRoot.php");` seems to register correctly the XmlRoot annotations but other JMS annotations still fail.

Thanks.

Comment: The namespace is imported as `use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS` and the annotation is `@JMS\XMLRoot`

Comment: Try to change the JMS alias to something else then JMS. Perhaps it's clashing with the JMS namespace. Also, I'm not sure why you've put additional calls to registerFile() and registerAutoloaderNamespace(). Call to registerLoader() should be sufficient.

Comment: Changed the alias to something else doesn't work. I've put the other call there to illustrate our attempts to fixing the issue (as far as I understand the annotations are loaded in bootstrap.php.cache so we don't need to add anything there?)

Comment: Note that the call to registerFile() did register the XmlRoot annotation correctly but obv it then failed in the next JMS annotation so it seems like we could manually register all the annotations and that would work but it seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: Remove the calls to registerFile() and registerAutoloaderNamespace(). You don't need them. Dump composer's autoload classmap and check if annotation classes can be found in there.

Comment: Ok we found the issue. We used XMLRoot instead of XmlRoot in the annotation, and had a different typo in the next annotations :facepalm:. We are still not sure why when we loaded it using registerFile() it worked. Thanks for your help all!

Answer (score 2):

you have to edit the vendor/autoload.php file,like below:

```
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

$loader = ComposerAutoloaderInitb6ddad78dfb081b4ad47d02feb034c25::getLoader();
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

return $loader;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import namespace to Your `Entity` with an alias:

```
<?php

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS

class SomeClass
{
    /**
     * @JMS/XMLRoot
     */
    public $someProperty
}
```

Got same problem with `Doctrine` elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason for the same error:-

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@JMS\Serializer\Annotation\XMLRoot" in
class Class\Namespace\ClassName does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

is a missing call to `AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation here - http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/configuration

> If you are using the standalone library and you want to use annotations, the annotation registry must be initialized:
>
> **Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');**